# Optimize the cost of steel $S$

Tags: calculus, economics

$$S= 10 \ell^{0.4} C^{0.6}$$
$$\text{Total Cost}= 60\ell+100C$$
$$40000= 10 \ell^{0.4} C^{0.6}$$
$S$ is the function of $\ell$ and $C$?
We have to minimize the total cost
How to proceed in this problem??
I know I'll have to minimize the cost for that I'll have to minimize l and C which are variables here

Comment: what is S. What is C? What is l? Some specifications please?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

From the constraint $$40000=10 \ell^{2/5}\,C^{3/5}$$ you can extract $$C=\frac{800000 \sqrt[3]{2}}{\ell^{2/3}}$$ which makes $$\text{Total Cost}=60 \ell + \frac{80000000 \sqrt[3]{2}}{\ell^{2/3}}$$ what you want to minimize.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: yeah thanks a lot

Comment: @Michael Hardy. Thanks for the edit !